# Why are the propagators in old-fashioned QED oblique, while in modern QED they are horizontal (or vertical)?

Tags: time, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, propagator

In old-fashioned Quantum Electrodynamics, one can find diagrams such as these (probably Stückelberg was the first to use this notation, a kind of predecessor of Feynman diagrams):

[image]

In modern QED this process (electron-electron scattering) is represented by this [Feynman diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram):

[image]

I didn't bother to reduce this picture in size (which maybe is a good indicator which one is of most importance).
What's the difference between the two? Why are the [propagators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) depicted differently?
Does another diagram have to be added to the first one (a kind of mirrored version wrt time; it will still represent electron-electron scattering) to obtain the second (symmetrical) diagram? Are there other factors involved (which)?

Comment: In pre-Feynman diagrams, the time ordering mattered. One Feynman diagram with $N$ vertices corresponds to $N!$ old-fashioned perturbation theory diagrams.

Comment: @mikestone yes. it's called "old fashioned perturbation theory", and energy is not conserved at vertices. It is the origin of the pop sci "b/c HUP, virtual particles can borrow energy from the vacuum for a short period of time"; however, in the manifestly Lorentz covariant Feynman view, that's not how it works.

Comment: I'm very glad that this question is reopened. I don't need an answer anymore because in the long list of comments it was made clear to me. Especially by...uuuuh...well, I'm not gonna write here who they were. I think they know that for themselves.  So I'd like to say again: thanx!!!